# Adding item to Array collection api platform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a Question entity the relate 'OneToMany' with Answer. The question is how to create a custom endpoint with path='question/{id}/add_answer' to add an answer to a certain question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont really need a custom endpoint for that. You could add a answer posting to the asnwer question with something like this:

```
{
  "question": {"id": 2},
  "message": "Hello, this is my answer for question with id 2"
}
```

You must add post group in the answer properties that you want to post (message in this case), in the question relations in the answer property and id of question entity.

If you still want to create a custom operation for that. You should add this annotation to your question entity below to the collection operations:

```
 *          "add_answer"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "path"="/question/{id}/add_answer",
 *              "controller"=AddAnswerAction::class,
 *              "denormalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"add-answer"} //add this group to the properties that you want to post. You probable has to create and field in this entity. You dont need add it to the bbdd.
 *              }
 *          },
```

Under the Controller dir, you have to create AddAnswerAction.php and do the logic. Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

final class AddAnswerAction
{

    public function __construct(
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Question $question)
    {
         //logic
    }
}
```

By the way. The 1st option is the recommended.

Comment: You answer would work, the point is I have designed that the answer doesn't know the question so it's unidirectional relationship from Question entity side 'for certain reasons'.

Answer (score 0):

In loopback we can make by this way.

```
http:{
        verb:'patch',
        path:'/:questionId/add_answer/'
    }
```

Comment: More details, please

Comment: This is an example of my code
`Jobboard.remoteMethod('updatePost', {
returns:{
    type:"object",
    root:true
},
accepts:[
    {
        arg:"jobPostId",
        type:"string",
        required:true,
        http:{source:"path"}
    },
    {
        arg:"data",
        type:"object",
        required:true,
        http:{source:"body"}
    },
    {
        arg:"request",
        type:"object",
        http:{source:"req"}
    }
],
description: "This method used to update Job by Partner",
http:{
    verb:'patch',
    path:'/:jobPostId/updatePost/'
}
})`

Comment: Or you can create relations between question and answers. So methods will appear in the explorer.